# 2MM row load job failed after 2 hours, but no useful error message generated

Tags: google-bigquery

Here's a screenshot of my load job. it says "Unexpected. Please try again." without any additional information. Is there some way to get more detail? or can someone at google take a closer look at the logs and tell my why it failed?

bq shows:

Job tzgqnxt:job_016afefcfc0a42089822d621cf3d6ace

Job Type    State      Start Time      Duration   Bytes Processed

---

load       FAILURE   27 Jul 10:32:05   2:00:09

Errors encountered during job execution. Unexpected. Please try again.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I'm wondering if it hit a 2 hour time limit?

Comment: I've also looked at the limits listed here, and I don't think I'm busting any. https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/developers_guide#importingatable

Comment: After reading this, I'm wondering if it might be an unterminated quote. I'll check when I get to the machine. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562184/unexpected-error-while-loading-data

Comment: The logs for this job are unavailable for the next 24 hours due to scheduled maintenance. I'll let you know when they're back and see if I have any more information.

Comment: thanks -- the two days are up :)

Comment: there is nothing in this document on a two hour limit: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/quota-policy

Comment: I've filed a doc bug that says we should document the 2 hour limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that this job was killed at almost exactly 2 hours, it looks like you hit the two hour limit for import and export jobs. This job likely shouldn't have taken 2+ hours though -- I looked at the job logs, it looks like we encountered some problems with the CSV at about 5.5 million rows. Is there any chance you could give me (tigani@google.com) read access to the file in google storage so that I can debug further?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I gave you permission.

Comment: so that file looks to be 3.5 GB compressed, and if I decompress it it I run out of disk space on a device with 37GB free.... that makes it unsurprising that it takes more than 2 hours to import.

Comment: yes, its almost 200gb uncompressed:)

so you think the problem is the 2 hour time limit?

does BQ decompress the file on the fly, or does it decompress it first, then import it?

Comment: Yes, I think you're hitting the time limie. Currently, BigQuery decompresses on the fly, but since compressed files can not be seeked in, we have to process the file synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `bq` installed? If so, you can try calling `bq show -j <that job id>` to see if there's any additional information.

Note that if you are hitting a timeout problem, you could work around it by splitting the file into a few chunks and doing several imports, all with the same destination table. The end result will be the same.

Comment: bq doesn't show anything more.  

i'd rather have an authoritative answer on any timelimits rather rather than spending my time figuring out if there is one